# Terraform: How to install multiple versions of provider plugins?

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I am trying to deploy Azure resources through Terraform 0.12 with azurerm provider.
I have AKS module which works fine with azurerm version 2.5.0, but breaks with 2.9.0.
On the other hand Postgresql module works with version 2.9.0 but breaks with 2.5.0
I want to deploy both resources through a single terraform apply.

I tried below configuration but it fails at initialize phase.

```
  provider "azurerm" {
  version = "=2.9.0"
  }

  provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "latest"
  version = "=2.5.0"
  }
```

---

```
$ terraform.exe init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Checking for available provider plugins...

No provider "azurerm" plugins meet the constraint "=2.5.0,=2.9.0".
```

The version constraint is derived from the "version" argument within the
provider "azurerm" block in configuration. Child modules may also apply
provider version constraints. To view the provider versions requested by each
module in the current configuration, run "terraform providers".

To proceed, the version constraints for this provider must be relaxed by
either adjusting or removing the "version" argument in the provider blocks
throughout the configuration.

> Error: no suitable version is available

How to install both provider versions and point AKS module to v2.5.0 and point Postgres module to v2.9.0

Comment: This is not possible with the current version of terraform (0.12 and 0.13)

Answer (score -1):

Break the code into Modules and add provider section in your module and call the modules differently in your main.tf file.

Example

modules/AKS

```
provider {
}
```

modules/DB

```
provider {
}
```

Now call your modules differently

main.tf

```
module "AKS" {
  source = "../modules/AKS"
}

module "DB" {
  source = "../modules/DB"
}
```

Comment: Used below configuration:
AKS main.tf
`provider "azurerm" {
  version = "= 2.5.0"
}`

Postgrsql main.tf
`provider "azurerm" {
  version = "= 2.9.0"
}`

Still getting same error after running "terraform init"
No provider "azurerm" plugins meet the constraint "= 2.5.0,= 2.9.0"