# terraform to use different provider for one resource block

Tags: terraform

We are using `hashicorp/google` provider @3.90.0 version but for one specific resource we want to use `hashicorp/google` provider @4.31.0 and continue using `@3.90.0` everywhere else. Is there a way to use different provider version for just one block:

as of now `provider.tf`:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13.0"
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = ">= 3.45, <= 3.90.0"

    }
  }
}
```

`main.tf` here in this block we want to use version `4.31.0` for google provider:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "cdn-bucket" {
  project       = var.project_id
  name          = "cdn-${var.project_id}"
  location      = "US"
  storage_class = "MULTI_REGIONAL"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66430076/8343484?

Comment: Looks like its not possible. I found this:

```
There is no way to use multiple versions of the same provider in the same configuration. You will need to either make all of your modules have some provider version they are all mutually compatible with, or to split your configuration into multiple parts so that each part can depend on a different version of the provider and be applied separately.
```

Comment: @Ajayk this is possible, check the link Marko sent in his comment. Basically you need 2 providers (e.g. google with google 3 version, and google4 with google 4.31.0 version). When declaring your cdn-bucket resource, just add provider = google4 in this specific resource.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use multiple versions of the same provider in the same configuration. You will need to either make all of your modules have some provider version they are all mutually compatible with, or to split your configuration into multiple parts so that each part can depend on a different version of the provider and be applied separately.